# How to utilize javascript on Adobe Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver, cs4

I am working on my personal website and am learning javascript (started yesterday) -

My computer is a Mac and I couldn't find on the Internet how to utilize javascript on Adobe Dreamweaver CS4. Specifically, I am trying to use a photo slideshow called [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/). On PCs, they say to drop the .js file into one of Dreamweaver's folders.

These are the steps:

Galleria 1.2 is currently in beta. You try it yourself in it's simpler form by following these simple steps:

1. Download Galleria (Nightly build)
2. Unpack etc.
3. Include jquery and Galleria:

   < script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">< /script>

   < script src="galleria/src/galleria.js">< /script>
4. Load a theme:

   < script>Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/galleria.classic.js');< /script>
5. Add images:

   < div class="images">< img src="me.jpg">< img src="you.jpg">
6. Fire upp Galleria:

   < script>$('.images').galleria();< /script>

Is step 3 calling jQuery and Galleria for me so I don't need to put the .js file somewhere? Or do I need to upload the .js file to my website and then change this line to suit -

< script src="galleria/src/galleria.js">

Can someone enlighten me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first script tag, `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>` is including the script from an external server, googleapis.com. You don't need to worry about that script.

The second one, `<script src="galleria/src/galleria.js">` points to galleria.js in the galleria/src folder. It's a relative path so the galleria folder should be in the same folder as your web page file.

If you upload the galleria.js file to galleria/src, you won't need to change any lines.

Comment: Thanks! I FTP-ed the galleria.js to my website. Should work now!